# How to pass undefined and null through a prototype?

Tags: javascript

I have `dynamic code` that is `self creating`. Under `certain conditions`, only certain types are allow through some `if statements`.

**What currently works**

- object
- boolean
- number
- string
- symbol
- function

**What breaks the code**

1. null
2. undefined

If the code tries to check if it is a `null` or `undefined` everything falls apart. Or if it is a `null` or `undefined` and I want to check if it is a string, it falls apart.

I was wondering if there is a way to pass the `null` or `undefined` through?

## Demo

Demo works up until it gets ready to check for null.

```js
function type(obj) {
  obj = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).split(' ')[1].replace(']', '');
  return obj;
}
String.prototype.is = function(what) {
  if (/\b(string|str|s)\b/i.test(what)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
Array.prototype.is = function(what) {
  if (/\b(array|arr|a)\b/i.test(what)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
Object.prototype.is = function(what) {
  let results = type(this)
  let regex = new RegExp('\\b' + results + '\\b', 'i')
  if (regex.test(what)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};

unknown1 = 'hello world'
unknown2 = /a/g
unknown3 = null // Failed to pass through prototype - suppose to log true
unknown4 = undefined // Failed to pass through prototype - suppose to log false
unknown5 = 9

console.log(unknown1.is('string or regexp'))
console.log(unknown2.is('object'))
console.log(unknown3.is('null'))
console.log(unknown4.is('number'))
console.log(unknown5.is('string, number, or object'))
```

Comment: `null` and `undefined` are primitives that do not have wrapper objects, so you cannot set a prototype method on it, hence why you get a cannot read property error

Comment: Is it possible to wrap prototypes in an `if statement` and return `null` before it's broken?

Comment: Don't use prototype methods for this.

Answer (score -1):

## Shorter and Faster Solution

Also… Doesn't Break

```js
function type(obj) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).split(' ')[1].replace(']', '');
}

function is(obj, what) {
  let regex = new RegExp('\\b(' + type(obj) + ')\\b', 'i');
  if (regex.test(what)) {return true;}
  return false;
}

unknown1 = 'hello world'
unknown2 = /a/g
unknown3 = null
unknown4 = undefined
unknown5 = 9
unknown6 = function name() {}
unknown7 = true
unknown8 = {}


console.log(is(unknown1, 'a string or function'))
console.log(is(unknown2, 'a regexp'))
console.log(is(unknown3, 'null, regexp, or string'))
console.log(is(unknown4, 'string'))
console.log(is(unknown5, 'string'))
console.log(is(unknown6, 'regexp'))
console.log(is(unknown7, 'a boolean'))
console.log(is(unknown8, 'an object'))
```